# How would I make this whole program repeat after the person enters an answer? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I'm making this subitizing trainer. It trains you to know how many of something there are without physically counting them. The program creates a window and then generates a random number of circles. Then you enter how many circles you saw, it then tells you whether you were right or wrong.

Now I want the whole program to repeat after you press a certain button on your keyboard, how would I do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


def new_circle():
    c1 = random.randint(1, 500)
    c2 = random.randint(1, 500)
    canvas.create_oval(c1, c2, c1+45, c2+45, fill='black')


def enter_text(event):
    global number_of_circles
    answer = int(text.get())
    if answer == number_of_circles:
        frame.destroy()
        label = Label(window, text="That's right")
        label.pack()

    else:
        frame.destroy()
        label = Label(window, text="That's wrong")
        label.pack()





window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=1000, height=1000)

number_of_circles = random.randint(1, 2)

for i in range(number_of_circles):
    new_circle()

canvas.pack()

window.after(750, canvas.destroy)

frame = Frame()
text = Entry(frame, width=50)

text.pack()
text.focus()

enter = Button(frame, command=enter_text)
enter.pack()
frame.pack()

window.bind('<Return>', enter_text)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use a class and handle user input errors:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

DIMENSIONS      = [500, 500]
MAX_NB_CIRCLES  = 5
SIZE_CIRCLE     = 45

class ReflexApp(Tk):

    number_of_circles = None
    frame             = None
    text              = None
    canvas            = None
    label             = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry(str(DIMENSIONS[0])+"x"+str(DIMENSIONS[1]))
        self.bind('<Return>', self.binded_enter_text)
        self.new_circles()

    def new_guess(self, error):
        if not error:
            self.frame = Frame()
            self.text = Entry(self.frame, width=50)
            self.text.pack()
            self.text.focus()
            self.enter = Button(self.frame, text='Validate', command=self.enter_text)
            self.enter.pack()
            self.frame.pack()
        else:
            self.after(750, self.label.destroy)

    def new_circles(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=DIMENSIONS[0], height=DIMENSIONS[1])
        self.number_of_circles = random.randint(1, MAX_NB_CIRCLES)
        for i in range(self.number_of_circles):
            c1 = random.randint(1, DIMENSIONS[0]-SIZE_CIRCLE)
            c2 = random.randint(1, DIMENSIONS[1]-SIZE_CIRCLE)
            self.canvas.create_oval(c1, c2, c1+SIZE_CIRCLE, c2+SIZE_CIRCLE, fill='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.after(750, self.canvas.destroy)
        self.new_guess(False)

    def binded_enter_text(self, event):
        self.enter_text()

    def enter_text(self):
        try:
            answer = int(self.text.get())
        except:
            self.label = Label(self, text="Wrong input")
            self.label.pack()
            self.new_guess(True) 
        if answer == self.number_of_circles:
            self.frame.destroy()
            self.label = Label(self, text="That's right")
            self.label.pack()
        else:
            self.frame.destroy()
            self.label = Label(self, text="That's wrong")
            self.label.pack()
        self.after(750, self.new_circles)
        self.after(750, self.label.destroy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app=ReflexApp()
    my_app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT :** There is a traceback error, but 'Enter' key works

Comment: Could you have written this same script without using classes? What was the specific benefit of using them in this?

Comment: Yes it is possible to write it without using a class (may take more time). Using classes allows you to easily manipulate variables across the methods, using the class attributes (here you have label, text, canvas, ..). Also, when using UI, it is a good practice to have classes, as it will allow you to write lite codes (here it is pretty simple, however it the future you will may use more classes and code tends to become difficult to read if Class not use). Also, classes can be used as object, and you could use them outside.

Answer (score 0):

simplest answer without making major changes in your script would be. You could get all the script inside a new function and call that function whenever you want to repeat showing window with circles and ask for input with frame ;

```
def call_window():
    number_of_circles = random.randint(1, 2)

    def new_circle(canvas):
        c1 = random.randint(1, 500)
        c2 = random.randint(1, 500)
        canvas.create_oval(c1, c2, c1 + 45, c2 + 45, fill='black')

    def enter_text():

        answer = int(text.get())
        if answer == number_of_circles:
            frame.destroy()
            label = Label(window, text="That's right")
            label.pack()

        else:
            frame.destroy()
            label = Label(window, text="That's wrong")
            label.pack()

    window = Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(window, width=1000, height=1000)



    for i in range(number_of_circles):
        new_circle(canvas)

    canvas.pack()

    window.after(750, canvas.destroy)

    frame = Frame()
    text = Entry(frame, width=50)

    text.pack()
    text.focus()

    enter = Button(frame, command=enter_text)
    enter.pack()
    frame.pack()




    window.bind('<Return>', enter_text)


    window.mainloop()

call_window()
call_window()
```

With above script whenever you do call_window() it will call your screen with circles and then ask for input.

Then you with simple while loop you can keep asking for user input and depending on that you can call_window():

```
is_on = True

while is_on:
    user = input("Do you want to continue? Y/N: ").lower()

    if user == "y":
        call_window()
    else:
        break
```

With this way after user clicks button, has to close frame window. To improve GUI behaviour and User Experience I believe object oriented tkinter window would be better ; [https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-object-oriented-window/#:~:text=Defining%20a%20Tkinter%20object-oriented%20window&text=How%20it%20works.,to%20display%20the%20root%20window](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-object-oriented-window/#:%7E:text=Defining%20a%20Tkinter%20object-oriented%20window&text=How%20it%20works.,to%20display%20the%20root%20window).

Comment: Thanks! You said 'without making major changes in your script', what would be the optimal way to do this if you were to make major changes to the script?

Comment: Best way would be using classes :)

Answer (score 0):

I also made a major change to improve, and accordingly, this rule applies to Python 3.5 and later(`Walrus`). I also removed the trap `try/except`. I used **double space** and **single space** in functions. Btw, for constant. There will be **no extra whitespace**. I added `asyncio`. Must improve improve upon @Sramazoth.

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import asyncio


DIMENSIONS = [500, 500]
MAX_NB_CIRCLES = 5
SIZE_CIRCLE = 45

class ReflexApp(Tk):
    number_of_circles = None
    frame  = None
    text = None
    canvas = None
    label  = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry(str(DIMENSIONS[0])+"x"+str(DIMENSIONS[1]))
        self.bind('<Return>', self.binded_enter_text)
        self.new_circles()

        
    def new_guess(self, error):
        if not error:
            self.frame = Frame()
            self.text = Entry(self.frame, width=50)
            self.text.pack()
            self.text.focus()
            self.enter = Button(self.frame, text='Validate', command=self.enter_text)
            self.enter.pack()
            self.frame.pack()
        else:
            False
            

    def new_circles(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=DIMENSIONS[0], height=DIMENSIONS[1])
        self.number_of_circles = random.randint(1, MAX_NB_CIRCLES)
        for i in range(self.number_of_circles):
            c1 = random.randint(1, DIMENSIONS[0]-SIZE_CIRCLE)
            c2 = random.randint(1, DIMENSIONS[1]-SIZE_CIRCLE)
            self.canvas.create_oval(c1, c2, c1+SIZE_CIRCLE, c2+SIZE_CIRCLE, fill='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.after(750, self.canvas.destroy)
        self.new_guess(False)


    def binded_enter_text(self, event):
        self.enter_text()


    def enter_text(self):
        (answer := int(self.text.get()))
        if answer == self.number_of_circles:
            self.frame.destroy()
            self.label = Label(self, text="That's right")
            self.label.pack()           
        else:
            self.frame.destroy()
            self.label = Label(self, text="That's wrong")
            self.label.pack()
        self.after(750, self.new_circles)
        self.after(750, self.label.destroy)


async def main() -> None:
    my_app=ReflexApp()
    my_app.mainloop()

asyncio.run(main())
```